# Edit dynamically generated list item's text without icons in it

Tags: javascript, edit

I'm playing with the famous task list app exercise and would like to extend it through an edit button within each dynamically added `<li>`.

as for now my `<li>`'s look like this:

```
<li class="list-item">
  "some text from my input"
  <a class="delete-task">... //delete icon
  <a class="edit-task">...   //edit icon
</li>
```

Now, if i set the `<li>` to `contenteditable='true'`, i can edit it's text but also remove those icons and even write something inside them, which is crazy.

Question: Using vanilla js, how to write a function that would, after clicking the edit icon, allow me to change the text only?

Here's a linkt to visualize my `<li>`:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/kt4zM.jpg

Comment: Damn, that's simple :)
Thanks @Andreas,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrap the text in a `<span>` tag and only make that editable.

```js
document.querySelector("a.edit-task")
  .addEventListener("click", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var span = this.previousElementSibling;
    span.contentEditable = span.contentEditable == "true" ? "false" : "true";
  });
```

```css
.list-item span { margin-right: 10px; }
.list-item img { height: 16px; }
span[contenteditable="true"] { background-color: yellow; }
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="list-item">
    <span>lorem ipsum dolor amet...</span>
    <a class="edit-task" href="#">
      <img src="data:image/svg+xml;base64,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"
        alt="edit" title="edit" />
    </a>
  </li>
</ul>
```